# exc_bad_acccess when adding to NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, memory, nsoperationqueue

I've subclassed NSOperation and - (void) main is ok, (since it worked before using NSOperation), I've also stepped through the init method and the variables are initialized correctly.
All tough after the -(id) initWithSampleBuffer: is done and I'm trying to add the uploadOperation to the NSOperationQueue:

```
UploadOperation *ulOp = [[UploadOperation alloc] initWithSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
[queue addOperation:ulOp]; //here i get exc_bad_access
[ulOp release];
```

I get exc_bad_access. I've tried breakpoints and I can see that queue exists and so do ulOp.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, since to my understanding exc_bad_access occurs when you're trying to pass a "message" to something that is already deallocated, and clearly, none of them are.

```
- (id)initWithSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) aSampleBuffer {
    sampleBuffer = aSampleBuffer;

    VideoStreamViewController *vc = [VideoStreamViewController shared];
    ul = [[Uploader alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL alloc] filePath:@"" delegate:vc doneSelector:@selector(didFinishUpload:) errorSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];

    return self;
}
```

however the Uploader stuff, isn't the problem (i've removed it and still get the same result). and from what i can se there no problem with the CMSampleBuffer object, it is initialized!

init of queue:

in .h:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *queue;
```

in .m:

```
@synthesize queue;
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

Comment: How does `initWithSampleBuffer:` initializer look like?

Comment: there you have it. i don't thin there is a problem there. also i add the initialization of the NSOperationQueue.

Comment: Where does `self` come from? You are doing your object initialization in wrong way. Add `self = [super init]` as first line of your initializer. Also from looks I'd suggest you read guide about multithreaded programming & operation queues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling `[super init]` inside your constructor?

Assuming you're subclassing NSOperation (or NSObject etc...), you probably should!